# Table not updated by trigger and procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, procedure

I have a system which people do orders on, each order has actions, and a table exists called cm_ord_order_action. Sometimes actions fail, so I need to make a trigger that gets information for the failed order action and populates a table called cm_ord_failed_order.

the trigger is shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CM.TRGID_CM_ORD_FAILED_ORDER
AFTER UPDATE ON CM.CM_ORD_ORDER_ACTION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   IF (:new.STATUS = 'FA') THEN
        CM.CM_FAILED_ORDER_MLT(:new.order_unit_id, :new.order_id, :new.action_type);
   END IF;
END;
/
```

This trigger passes parameters to a procedure which updates the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CM_FAILED_ORDER_MLT(
v_order_unit_id NUMBER,
v_order_id in NUMBER,
v_action_type in VARCHAR)

AS
v_lob varchar(100);
v_step varchar(100);
v_error varchar(200);

BEGIN

SELECT
    ITEM.LOB_NAME, ST.STEP_NAME, ASS.STEP_ERROR
    INTO v_lob, v_step, v_error           
FROM
    CM.CM_ORD_ORDER_ACTION OA 
    INNER JOIN CM.CM_ORD_ASSIGNMENTS ASS 
        ON OA.ORDER_UNIT_ID = ASS.ORDER_ACTION_ID 
    INNER JOIN CM.CM_ORD_PROCESS_STEP ST
        ON ST.ORD_PROCESS_STEP_ID = ASS.STEP_ID 
    INNER JOIN CM.CM_ORD_AP_ITEM ITEM
        ON ITEM.AP_SUBSCRIBER_ID = OA.AP_SUBSCRIBER_ID
WHERE ASS.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'FA'
AND OA.ORDER_ID = v_order_id
AND OA.ORDER_UNIT_ID = v_order_unit_id
GROUP BY OA.ORDER_UNIT_ID, ITEM.LOB_NAME, ST.STEP_NAME, ASS.STEP_ERROR;

INSERT INTO CM_ORD_FAILED_ORDER (ORDER_ID, FAILED_DATE, ORDER_ACTION_ID, ACTION_TYPE, LOB, STEP, ERROR)
  VALUES (v_order_id, sysdate, v_order_unit_id, v_action_type, v_lob, v_step, v_error);

END CM_FAILED_ORDER_MLT;
/
```

There is probably something wrong here because:
A - Even though the trigger is for after update on cm_ord_order_action, when the trigger is enabled, the status is not being updated, but when I disable the trigger the status is updated.

B - the table cm_ord_failed_order is not being populated with the information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use a before update?

Comment: How is the update being performed? Is the procedure throwing an exception (no data found?) which the trigger passes on, but that is being squashed/ignored by whatever is doing the update, perhaps? Have you tried doing an update manually to see what happens, or any debugging?

Comment: My guess is that your trigger throws an error.  My guess is that it's a mutating table error.  Is that what you're actually seeing?  Do you have some piece of code that is swallowing those errors?  I would expect that you would want to remove the reference to `CM_ORD_ORDER_ACTION` from your procedure-- you'd need to pass in all the values from that table that you need from the trigger.

Comment: @AlexPoole The update is being performed via a script which update the state in cm_ord_order_action to 'FA' as soon as an order fails. I receive no errors, the trigger just fails to update cm_ord_order_action  status to 'FA' and fails to update cm_ord_failed_order.

Comment: @JustinCave I manually executed the procedure and the table cm_ord_failed_order was updated, therefore the procedure  should be working fine right?

Comment: @Iommiund - the procedure may be fine on its own, but when the procedure is called from the trigger the query it performs will get a mutating table error, because it refers to the table the trigger is against. If you aren't seeing that error then something in your script is catching and ignoring it, either with a `when others` handler, or perhaps your script is discarding the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the mutating table error your script is somehow ignoring or discarding by doing the insert directly in the trigger, where you have the details from the row being updated in the `:NEW` pseudorecord and don't have to query it again. You can also do an `insert...select` without needing local variables.

I think this is a rough translation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CM.TRGID_CM_ORD_FAILED_ORDER
AFTER UPDATE ON CM.CM_ORD_ORDER_ACTION
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.STATUS = 'FA')
BEGIN 

  INSERT INTO CM_ORD_FAILED_ORDER (ORDER_ID, FAILED_DATE, ORDER_ACTION_ID, ACTION_TYPE,
    LOB, STEP, ERROR)
  SELECT
    DISTINCT :new.ORDER_ID, sysdate, :new.Order_Unit_Id, :new.Action_Type,
      ITEM.LOB_NAME, ST.STEP_NAME, ASS.STEP_ERROR
  FROM
    CM.CM_ORD_ASSIGNMENTS ASS
    INNER JOIN CM.CM_ORD_PROCESS_STEP ST
        ON ST.ORD_PROCESS_STEP_ID = ASS.STEP_ID 
    CROSS JOIN CM.CM_ORD_AP_ITEM ITEM
  WHERE ASS.ORDER_ACTION_ID = :new.ORDER_UNIT_ID
  AND ASS.COMPLETION_STATUS = :new.STATUS
  AND ITEM.AP_SUBSCRIBER_ID = :new.AP_SUBSCRIBER_ID;

END CM_FAILED_ORDER_MLT;
/
```

The `DISTINCT` (instead of grouping) and `CROSS JOIN` suggest you're missing a join condition in your original query, but without your table structures and data that may not be the case.

Alternatively you could keep the insert in a procedure, but pass `:new`AP_SUBSCRIBER_ID` as another argument, since that seems to be the only column you need from the mutating table that you aren't already passing in.

Your trigger could also be a `BEFORE UPDATE` rather than `AFTER UPDATE`.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason the OP included the `cm.cm_ord_order_action` table in the query in the first place was because the cm_ord_ap_item wasn't joined to any of the other tables in that query. However, there's more than one way to skin that cat! *{;-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Alex's solution that avoids the need for a cross join would be to change the procedure to:

```
create or replace procedure cm_failed_order_mlt (v_order_unit_id number,
                                                 v_order_id in number,
                                                 v_action_type in varchar,
                                                 v_ap_subscriber_id in cm.cm_ord_order_action.ap_subscriber_id%type)

as
  v_lob varchar(100);
  v_step varchar(100);
  v_error varchar(200);
begin
  select distinct lob_name
  into   v_lob
  from   cm.cm_ord_ap_item
  where ap_subscriber_id = v_ap_subscriber_id;

  select distinct st.step_name, ass.step_error
  into   v_step, v_error           
  from   cm.cm_ord_assignments ass
         inner join cm.cm_ord_process_step st on st.ord_process_step_id = ass.step_id
  where  ass.completion_status = 'FA'
  and    ass.order_action_id = v_order_id
  and    oa.order_unit_id = v_order_unit_id;

  insert into cm_ord_failed_order (order_id, failed_date, order_action_id, action_type, lob, step, error)
    values (v_order_id, sysdate, v_order_unit_id, v_action_type, v_lob, v_step, v_error);

end cm_failed_order_mlt;
/
```

Or, to remove the cross join in Alex's solution, simply replace it with a scalar subquery, e.g.:

```
select (select distinct lob_name from cm.cm_ord_ap_item where ap_subscriber_id = v_ap_subscriber_id), ...
```

Comment: I *suspect* the first query will get multiple rows, and that's what required the original query to have a group-by clause - so I left a `distinct` in there instead. But without the tables/data I'm speculating wildly. The grouping might have been redundant, or the duplicates might be coming from somewhere else...

Comment: ah yeah, good point. I'll add a distinct into that query too - I'm assuming from the main query that at most 1 row is returned. And, now you mention it, I'll switch out the group by in the 2nd query to a distinct as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like @JustinCave said, it is clear that you have mutating table [error](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions):

> Mutating table exceptions occur when we try to reference the
>   triggering table in a query from within row-level trigger code

On a trigger on `CM_ORD_ORDER_ACTION` you are selecting from that same table. Try  to redo the query in the procedure without referencing `CM_ORD_ORDER_ACTION`.